# fa fa icons is invisible

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i recently built a site and as its turns out a moment before i done the fafa icons just went blank. 
html code:

```html
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 text-center">
                  <div class="service-box mt-5 mx-auto">
                      <i class="fa fa-transgender fa-3x mb-3 sr-contact"></i>
                      <h3 dir="rtl" style="font-size:23px; text-align:right;">גיל מעבר, הפרעות בהורמוני מין כגון שיעור יתר בנשים, אקנה, נשירת שיער, שחלות פוליציסטיות, חסר הורמונאלי (טסטוסטרון נמוך) בגברים.</h3>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 text-center">
                  <div class="service-box mt-5 mx-auto">
                      <i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-3x mb-3 sr-contact"></i>
                      <h3 dir="rtl" style="font-size:23px; text-align:right;">בלוטת התריס – טיפול מצבי תת או יתר פעילות, איזון ומעקב במהלך הריון. קשריות בבלוטת התריס וגידולים ממאירים של תירואיד.</h3>

                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 text-center">
                  <div class="service-box mt-5 mx-auto">
                      <i class="fa fa-female fa-3x mb-3 sr-contact"></i>
                      <h3 dir="rtl" style="font-size:23px; text-align:right;">הפרעות אנדוקרינולוגיות בהריון, יעוץ טרום הריוני והריוני, הכנה להריון.</h3>

                  </div>
              </div>
```

but when i run the website it looks like this

[image]

Added a "style element from no where, i don't know how to delete it..

Comment: Why is this tagged `java`? Did you mean `javascript`?

Comment: can you share your css code please ?

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: @AaronGarton how can i know

Comment: @AlonBarel It's in the `href` of the `link` tag

Answer (score 1):

You have `opacity:0` set on the icon. This will make it not visible.

Comment: notice that this code is of the statoscope whice is visible in the 2nd row

Comment: It may function with the stethoscope but that's immaterial when your inspected element *shows* that the icons you're referencing as being invisible are, by design, invisible. We'd need to see more of your CSS / HTML to understand why `opacity:0` is being set on some of these items.